# Can someone explain why a controller method with name 'location' has some unexpected behavior in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I'm developing a project using Rails 3.2. 
In the project I have a controller that manages the user profiles with the basic CRUD methods in it.

At some point I added a new method called 'location', used to store the user profile location. This method only respond to JSON request.

After I added this method, the redirect, after the update profile action, is not behaving as before. It should redirect to edit action, but instead I get something like:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/profiles/1/edit
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 367ms (ActiveRecord: 23.1ms)
```

The edit profile action route has not changed and if I rename the 'location' action everything is working fine, so I guest the method name cause this, but I do not know why. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`location`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-location) is a method of `ActionController::Metal` which is available to your controller and you're overriding it this way.

You can retain the route `/users/:id/location` without the need to name the method `location`. E.g., in your `routes.rb`:

```
 resources :users do
   member do
     put :location, to: 'users#update_location' # Use the verb and the action name you see fit
   end
 end
```

and in your `UsersController`:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def update_location
     # Do your magic
   end
 end
```